# Android "constant expression required"

Tags: java, android

I don't want to use a duplicate flag.

```
package org.zzjbook.unit;
public class Unit {
    private static int flag = 1;
    public final static synchronized int getFlag() {
        return flag++;
    }
}
```

I use the above function to get the flag.

```
import static org.zzjbook.unit.Unit.getFlag;
public class Out {
    private final static int PRINT = getFlag();

    private Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case PRINT:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IDE gives the error.
"constant expression required".
How can I solve this mistake.

Comment: On what line? Also why don't you use an AtomicInteger?

Comment: @TimCastelijns why an AtomicInteger ?

Comment: What is the meaning of your `PRINT` variable? It looks very suspicious to me...

Comment: @Blackbelt seems like his Unit.getFlag is mimicing the behavior of it

Comment: @shmosel I want to use the out.print function to print the String on the Android. I hide some of the functions in the Out class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`switch` cases need to have constant expressions, as you were told. Change it to an `if` instead:

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (msg.what == PRINT) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why I use the "final" but it is not a constant

Comment: @zzjbook A constant has to be known at compile time. The value of `PRINT` in your code depends on when `Out` happens to initialize.

Comment: Thank you @shmosel, this is EXACTLY the last piece of information that I needed to figure out why the compiler was not happy.