# Constant expression required on the switch case

Tags: java, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I want to change layout when clicking the menu button "nav_calendar" or "nav_settings". but i'm having this error "Constant expression required" to both menu button.

This code below is my admin_activity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityAdminHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_calendar:
                    replaceFragment(new ScheduleFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    replaceFragment(new SettingsFragment());
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
```

And this is the nav_menu.xml

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_calendar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_calendar"
        android:title="@string/schedule"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="@string/Settings"/>
```

It is supposed to change fragment between the settings and the calendar menu.

Comment: It is exactly as the message says. Case labels must be constant expressions. The variables you are using aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer [Android "constant expression required"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38392009/android-constant-expression-required)
i change the switch statement to if-else statement.

```
  if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_calendar) {
            replaceFragment(new ScheduleFragment());
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.nav_settings) {
            replaceFragment(new SettingsFragment());
        }
```